# Cannot create FileTransferManager object

Tags: java, openfire, smack

I am trying to implement file transfer in my project but cannot create FileTransferManager object it says:

> FileTransferManager (org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection) in FileTransferManager cannot be applied to (org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection)

Here is my code:

```
 FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
            // Where connection is an object of XMPPTCPConnection
```

Using Smack 4.2.0 and Openfire server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking about the class org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferManager it has no public constructor however it has a static factory method:

```
public static synchronized FileTransferManager getInstanceFor(XMPPConnection connection)
```

so i would try the following:

```
FileTransferManager manager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
```

Are you sure that you imported a right class? Because you shouldn't be able to call its constructor at all.

Comment: Yes I have imported the right packages and I am working on latest smack library.
ps: I am working in java not on android.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the version of the smack jar.
With a recent version, such as 3.2.1 it should work.

Comment: As the other commet sais, if you are usign smack 4.2.0 and smack-extensions 4.2.0, the constructor of FileTransferManager can't be called.
Are you sure you are using compatible versions of the two packages?

Comment: Oops wrong library. I was using smackx instead of smack-extentions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use *getDefaultFileTransferManager* to achieve it :

```
public static FileTransferManager getDefaultFileTransferManager(FileTransferAuth fileTransferAuth)
                                                     throws ClientException,
                                                            ServiceException
```

reference:[official doc for Class FileTransferManager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas/storage-cloud/ftmap/oracle/cloudstorage/ftm/FileTransferManager.html)